# How to configure IIS 7.5 to access website using IP address?

Tags: iis-7.5

I order VPS hosting with Windows 2008 server and a dedicated IP Address , and install IIS 7.5 and DNS services on the server,I hosted 3 websites on the server, it works well, and I can use my domain to access my website, now I hope to use IP address to access my website, how can I configure IIS? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have just one IP address you can only have one website be accessible on that IP address. IIS will only allow you to bind one website without a host name to one IP address. If you have multiple websites on the same IP address, only one of these can be without a host name.

You can simply do this by clearing the host name field (in the bindings) for the website you want to be accessible on the IP address of your server.